# I am getting issue in Salesforce Maps License issue in Salesforce

Tags: packagelicense

I am trying to Install Package in Salesforce Maps & facing issue not showing manage License.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The number of licenses is not listed there. You will find the real number of Salesforce Maps licenses in Setup > Company Information > Permission Set Licenses > Salesforce Maps

If you want to give users the permission to use Maps, assign them the permission set "Salesforce Maps"

Comment: There is no salesforce Map License here either in Permission Set Licenses

Comment: Then I think you must contact your Salesforce accountmanager about that.